# Testing correlation or something else when comparing test scores? Using R

Tags: r, correlation

I am new to statistics in my M.Sc. thesis, and I would be grateful for some help.
I am testing a score (out of 9) to a score (out of 2). The first score is the person's "base knowledge" in a subject. The second score, out of 2, is the person's understanding of a subject, once presented with some information on an easy-to-use scale. I want to prove/test that the easy-to-use scale has a positive influence on the person's understanding, *regardless* of their prior knowledge (out of 9).

So, in a way, I want to prove that there is no(?) correlation between the test scores, i.e. you don't have to have the base knowledge in order to understand the easy-to-use scale.
I would be grateful for any advice on how to test this in R.

Many thanks.

Here's the sample data:

| Knowledge score | Understanding based on continuous score |
| --- | --- |
| 6.8 | 2 |
| 8 | 2 |
| 8 | 1 |
| 5.2 | 0 |
| 7.8 | 2 |
| 2.6 | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

You can run a correlation test, whose null hypothesis is that Pearson's correlation coefficient is equal to zero, and interpret the results. See [this CrossValidated post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/209686/how-to-interpret-r-pearsons-correlation-test).

```r
scores <- structure(list(
  Knowledge = c(6.8, 8, 8, 5.2, 7.8, 2.6), 
  Understanding = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L)), 
  class = "data.frame", 
  row.names = c(NA, -6L))

cor.test(scores$Knowledge, scores$Understanding)
#> 
#>  Pearson's product-moment correlation
#> 
#> data:  scores$Knowledge and scores$Understanding
#> t = 0.17857, df = 4, p-value = 0.867
#> alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  -0.7788409  0.8398765
#> sample estimates:
#>        cor 
#> 0.08893282
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The sample correlation coefficient is 0.0889 and the test gives you a p-value = 0.867. Therefore, you cannot reject the null. Like it is said in the Cross Validated post linked to above, `cor.test` also gives a 95% confidence interval for the point estimate r = 0.0889. That interval is (-0.78, 0.84) and contains the value 0. Once again, you cannot conclude that the *true* value of the correlation is not 0.

Another test you can run is a  one-sample, two-sided t-test, with the formula given in the CV post.

```r
r <- cor(scores$Knowledge, scores$Understanding)
n <- 2*nrow(scores)
tstat <- r*sqrt((2*nrow(scores) - 2)/(1 - r^2))
2*pt(-abs(tstat), df = n - 2)
#> [1] 0.7834335
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Note that the sample size is twice the number of rows of the data set `scores`. This is because you have two vectors, each of them of length equal to `nrow(scores)`. The test statistic is t = 0.282349. With n-2 = 10 degrees of freedom, the p-value is 0.78. And you cannot reject the null that the true value of the mean is 0.

Quoting the question, you have some evidence that

> there is no(?) correlation between the test scores, i.e., you don't have to have the base knowledge in order to understand the easy-to-use scale.

Comment: Thank you so much, this will take some time to digest but this is really helpful.

Comment: Can I ask why you used Pearson rather than Spearman? My understanding is that t-tests could not be used with ordinal data like test scores. Many thanks

Comment: @Miranda In the question, the column's name is (my emphasis) "Understanding based on *continuous* score". Are you binning the continuous data? Or was it ordinal from the beginning? I am no longer understanding the question.